# Python - Spyder: Invalid syntax - Why?

Tags: python, spyder

I am having an invalid syntax:

```
Upper_Stress=10 #Upper stress limit
Lower_Stress=0 #Lower stress limiy
Number_tests =[]
Normalized_Stress=[]
NumberStressLevels = [] #of stress levels for each component
base  = [0.5,0.5,0.5] #True Value: Theta_0, theta_1 and Sigma
Time_Scale =(np.exp(base[0]+base[1]*0.25)  #Generate failure time with scale = exp(alpha)
Time_Shape =(1/base[2]) #Generate failure time with shape =1/sigma


  Time_Shape = 1/base[2]#Generate failure time with (shape =1/sigma)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I delete the line that is causing the error, the invalid suntax moves to the next line which is:

```
s_0=[1,1]
```

It was working fine, suddenly it started giving invalid syntax. I am not seeing why !!

Comment: Your code and the error do not look the same (note the parentheses); is that correct?

Comment: If you can't spot the error in your current line, look at the previous line. You'll find a missing closing parenthesis.

Comment: You have mismatched parenthesis in the assignment to `Time_Scale`.

Comment: You don't need the outer parentheses in the assignments to either `Time_Scale` or `Time_Shape`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you miss parenthesis.

```py
Time_Scale =(np.exp(base[0]+base[1]*0.25)) # <=== here
```

But you should write it like this :

```py
Time_Scale = np.exp(base[0]+base[1]*0.25)
```

No need of parenthesis